# Settings variable in cordova config.xml for plugin installation

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a cordova app which needs several plugins and want to configure it using the config.xml file.
For instance, i need the 'plugin.google.maps' which needs the following variable when installing : API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID

If i do the following without specifying the plugin in `config.xml`, **this works**:

```
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add plugin.google.maps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="$MYKEY"
```

**It doesn't work** if i put in my config.xml file:

```
<feature name="cordova-plugin-app-version">
    <param name="id" value="plugin.google.maps" />
    <param name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="$MYKEY" />
</feature>
```

and then run

```
cordova platform add android
```

I get the following error:

```
Installing "plugin.google.maps" for android
Failed to install 'plugin.google.maps':Error: Variable(s) missing: API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID
at /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:299:23
at _fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
at flush (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

I'm having a hard time finding clear documentation on plugin configuration in config.xml. Is it the proper way to do this? What am i missing?

Comment: if the plugin install instructions tell you to put the API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID when you install it, do it that way, if they tell you to put the value on the config.xml, then put it on the config.xml, in this case you have to put it when you install it, so do it that way

Comment: My point is "shouldn't be the two methods equivalent?"

Comment: I don't think so, I think it will deppend on the plugin's developer who choose to do it one way or another

Comment: Anyway, you are doing it wrong, try with <preference name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="yourApiKeyHere" />, but I think it will still complain as it seems to expect the API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID on the install

Answer (score 5):

I think you can do it configuring your plugin as following :

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version">
   <param name="id" value="plugin.google.maps" />
   <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="$MYKEY" />
</plugin>
```

Hope that helps even after all this time ;)

Answer (score 0):

read this one it may be helpful for your "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" failure

https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/wiki/Phonegap-Usage

Answer (score -1):

Error and value name clearly says, you have to insert your key. 
You might have generated the key from google console.

If not follow these steps to generate a key and place .

- Go to https://code.google.com/apis/console/, and log in with your
  Google Account.
- The following will appear:
- Click on the "Create Project" button.
- In the list of services, find Google Maps API v3, and click on "off"
  to turn it on.
- In the next screen, check "I Agree..." and the click the "Accept"
  button. You will now see that the button next to Google Maps API v3
  has changed to "on".
- Then click "API Access" in the menu to the left. It will ask you to
  "Create an OAuth 2.0 client id...".
- In the next screen, provide a product name (e.g. "demo"), upload an
  image (if you want to) as a logo of your project, and click the
  "Next" button.
- In the next screen, choose Application type ("Web application"), and
  type in your web address, and then click the "Create Client Id"
  button.
- In the next screen, you have got an API key.

Save the key for future use.

Comment: Very detailed but not very useful unfortunately. I have my key since the method using `cordova plugin add` works. Thanks anyway